# How do I find the basis and dimension of a polynomial space?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $W=\{p(x)\in R[x] \mid p(x)=p(-x), \deg(p)\le3\}$ how to I find the basis of this? I already know how to find the basis and dimension of on a space defined by a linear equation. But how to do this?

Comment: The same way works just fine. Write what that condition means in terms of the coefficients of a polynomial of degree at most three and solve.

Comment: First note that $W$ is a *subspace* of real(?) polynomials of degree at most $3$.  Then consider the constraint $p(x)=p(-x)$ which is "defined by a linear equation."

Comment: @hardmath: how does it translate to a linear equation? I am getting an even polynomial. Essentially, by solving, I have: $ax^3 +cx=0$

Comment: What you have must hold for all $x$.  Let $x=0,1$ and you get two equations that determine $a,c$.  The other coefficients are free variables in solving $p(x)=p(-x)$.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$p(x)=p(-x) \implies$ p is even

thus a basis is: $\{1, x^2\}$

Comment: So, I extend it from there? Is that what you mean?

Comment: you don't have to extend anything he just gave you the answers. you just have to fill the gaps

Comment: @NirvanaGuha only the polynomials in the form $a+bx^2$ satisfy the given condition thus you have all the information you need

Comment: I get it now. For any $p \in W, p \in L\{1, x^2\}$ Is that right?

Comment: @NirvanaGuha precisely, thus the dimension is 2!

Answer (score 1):

$p(x)=p(-x)$ implies that you have even polynomial. To construct a basis, you can always use the "standart"/canonical basis that will span such polynomials